# Upload a file to google drive by an anonymous user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I use a Google Apps Script for that.

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function uploadFile(form) {
  var folderId = "folder_id";

  try {
    
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

    var blob = form.picToLoad;
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    
    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="main-heading">Main Heading</h1>
    <br/>
    <div id="formDiv">
      <form id="myForm">
        <input name="picToLoad" type="file" /><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="picUploadJs(this.parentNode)" />
      </form>
    </div>
  <div id="status" style="display: none">
  Uploading. Please wait...
</div>

</body>
<script>
  function picUploadJs(frmData) {
    document.getElementById('status').style.display = 'inline';
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
      .uploadFile(frmData)
  };

  function updateOutput() {
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('status');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = "The File was UPLOADED!";
  }
</script>
</html>
```

It all works fine when I'm authenticated within my domain (I use G Suite).

However, if I'm logged into Google as another user (e.g. a normal Gmail user) or not logged at all, I still can access the page, but the script doesn't execute properly with the following error in the console:

**Error**

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(...).processForm is not a function
  at picUploadJs (VM84 userCodeAppPanel:9)
  at HTMLInputElement.onclick (VM104 userCodeAppPanel:1)
```

No additional logs are shown in the Log at the level of Apps Script.

I have deployed the script as:

> **Execute the app as:** Me (and authorised it)
>
> **Who can access the app:** Anyone, even anonymous

So, I think all should work fine and anyone should be able to upload a file to my drive. Unfortunately that's not the case.

**Again, this happens only when I access the script from outside of my domain.**

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: odd. your publish settings are fine. try with a script copy.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by a script copy.

Comment: make a copy of the script and publish the copy, try it there.

Comment: hm... indeed after making and running a copy of the script, it actually worked. There must have been something wrongly initialised with the permissions. Super weird. Thanks for the tip @ZigMandel !

Comment: that means the issue is not in the code, but likely an internal issue in apps script, which you could report in their bug tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/78025

Answer (score 1):

As it was suggested in the comments by Zig Mandel, making a copy of the script and running it solved the problem. This restarted the process of authorisation so perhaps there was something wrongly initiallised with the permissions.